# Where is the Prometheus Engineer head in Star Wars Andor?

Tags: star-wars, prometheus, easter-egg, andor

Multiple sources (including Starwars.com) claim that an Engineer's (from Ridley Scott's Prometheus) severed head can be seen in Luthen Rael's antique shop. Yet there is no image online. I want to see it because Prometheus is my all time favorite sci-fi movie after Star Wars. Does anybody have an image?

Answer (score 10):

This article from StarWars.com states that that the head is in carbonite.

> **Carbonite Blocks:** *Looks like Darth Vader wasn’t the first to do the
> carbonite thing. There are several carbonite blocks in the gallery,
> some with more ordinary pieces like the necklace above, but **a few
> stand out for the subjects held within: the fertility idols from
> Raiders of the Lost Ark, an Engineer head from Prometheus, and more.**
> Can you find them all?*
>
> <sub><sup>[ANDOR: 10 EASTER EGGS WE FOUND IN LUTHEN’S GALLERY](https://www.starwars.com/news/andor-luthens-gallery-easter-eggs)</sup></sub>

We see a few carbonite blocks in Luthen's shop in Episode 4, one of which appears to have a small engineer head (severed at the base of the neck) looking sideways.

[image]

[image] [image]